# Routing libraries in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm going to choose a routing library for my React project and I was wondering, Is there other options other than "react-router", "[ui-router](https://github.com/ui-router/react)" and "[react-navigation](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another one called **simple-react-router** that uses dynamic and static routes. It is can be accessed [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-react-router).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but I wrote one you might like called [Buttermilk](https://buttermilk.js.org/). It's designed to be concise, very lightweight, and customizable.